# Chart can't be populated from data component [vue-highcharts wrapper]

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I'm starting with the Higcharts wrapper for vue. Currently I'm migrating the code of a stockchart that I was using outside vue without problems into the wrapper. Everything is going well except that I can't populate the chart from component data or computed variables. Only from hard-written array or from component props.

This is the code:

```html
<template>
  <highcharts
    class="stock"
    v-bind:constructor-type="'stockChart'"
    v-bind:options="config"
    v-bind:deepCopyOnUpdate="false"
  ></highcharts>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "stockChart",
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      config: {
        series: [{
          name: this.options.title,
          //data: [[1,3],[2,7],[3,9],[4,2],[5,0],[10,13]] //THIS WORKS!
          //data: this.options.plotData                   //THIS ALSO WORKS!!
          data: this.plotData                             //THIS DOESN'T...
        }],
        (...)
      },
      plotData: [[1,3],[2,7],[3,9],[4,2],[5,0],[10,13]]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // THIS ALSO ISN'T WORKING... THAT IS HOW I WANT IT TO WORK
    /*plotData: function(){
        return this.options.xData.map((e,i) => [e, this.options.yData[i]]);
    }*/
  }
}

</script>
<style scoped>
    .stock {
      width: 70%;
      margin: 0 auto
    }
</style>
```

I don't understand anything. The three methods should be equivalent. Why I can load data from props but not from data or computed? I can't find any good documentation about the vue wrapper to understand why is this happening.

Thanks for your help,

H25E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple. The reason is that the Vue defines all component data only after returning a whole `data` object, so you should not use `this` keyword to refer other component data within `data` definition. In order to make it work correctly, you should keep the `plotData` within component's `data`, but move the `config` into the computed properties. Take a look on the code below:

```js
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      plotData: [[1,3],[2,7],[3,9],[4,2],[5,0],[10,13]]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    config: function() {
      return {
        series: [{
          name: this.options.title,
          data: this.plotData
        }]
      }
    },
  }
```

Comment: Yes. That make it work. To understand it 100%... I can't define properties insie data{} dependent on each other?

Comment: Indeed. You should not try to do that because it will not work at all.